# unable to find popup element selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a project, wherein I am trying to automate the recaptchas. It has been going good so far, however I have run into an issue. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import *
from selenium.webdriver import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import requests
def initialize():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    return driver, wait
def input_info():
    name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/input")
    name.send_keys("usernamer12392103821")
    password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/input")
    password.send_keys("Password123")
    verify_password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[3]/input")
    verify_password.send_keys("Password123")
def select_recaptcha():
    men_menu = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[7]/div/div/div/iframe")))
    men_menu.click()
def get_to_sound():
    print("Searching for sound button")
    time.sleep(3)
    sound_butt_iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/iframe")
    print("Step one complete")
    driver.switch_to.frame(sound_butt_iframe)
    print("Step two complete")
    sound_butt = sound_butt_iframe.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button")
    print("Step 4 complete")
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    print("Step 5 complete")
    sound_butt.click()

### set up driver to go to reddit page!
driver, wait = initialize()
driver.get('https://old.reddit.com/login')
time.sleep(5)

#### Fill in the information necessary! (username, password)
input_info()
time.sleep(3)

print("Finding recaptcha")
select_recaptcha()
print("looking to see if successful!")
try:
    successful = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]")))
    print("Failed")
    print("Call to API with sound file!")
    try:
        get_to_sound()
    except:
        print("Failed")
        
except:
    print("Succeeded")
    print("Carry on")

time.sleep(10000)
```

Basically, it will open the https://old.reddit.com/login webpage, enter in a dummy username and password (twice for the confirm) and then click on the recaptcha. This all works great. It realizes that the recaptcha "pops" up, and then it tries to click on the audio button, which is where I run into the problem. I think because it is "stuck" in a new iframe html tag, the XPATH isn't being registered, but I'm not sure. Does someone know how I can get the driver to press the audio control button? I've attached a screenshot below of the html stuff that would be needed for this.
[image]
It's the highlighted button tag at the bottom that I am "worried" about
Thanks in advance.
Edit: Here's the picture of the button I am trying to press. I took a picture of the whole recaptcha thing, and the button I am trying to press is the headphones at the bottom. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get iframe as element with `driver.find_element(By.XPATH)`, and then `find_element(By.XPATH internal)` against that element

for that use switch_to_frame method

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='...']")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
# here access to internal elements by xpath
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it didn't work. Might you have any other ideas? The new updated line of code is this: `    sound_butt_iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[5]/div[4]/iframe")
    sound_butt = sound_butt_iframe.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button")
    sound_butt.click()`

Comment: actually, it's needed to use switch method. iframe, unlike other web elements is not accessible by simple reference. I've updated my answer, please check

Comment: It still fails. Would you like me to update the function in the main problem description so you can see? Also I tried both (for the second line) driver.switch_to.frame(iframe) and driver.switch_to_frame(iframe) in case that made a difference. The third line is still the line it fails it (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "") for the internal elements

Comment: it may be that frames appear only after some specific click, then you should perform find_element of that frame after that action - as before markup doesn't have it. you may also access the latest iframe from the frame collection - last element iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe") driver.switch_to_frame(iframes[-1])

Comment: Hmm. I tried the latest iframe thing where I added the [-1] when I swapped but that did nothing. And on the point of it being after some specific click, the code im trying to run does happen after the bot clicks the recaptcha to "open" if you will

Comment: could you show a latest code of get_to_sound function you've tried please?

Comment: Yup. I'll update the original question now. Its updated. Also so you know, it "breaks" after step one. However, when I went back without the [-1] (latest iframe) it gets to the second step

Comment: sorry, I've must confused you. for accessing internal elements after switch you still use driver. try to update to the following sound_butt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button")

Comment: Ok -> Almost perfect. It gets me to step 5 (last step) just before clicking the sound button which is where it breaks. Which is wierd, because the button should be able to be pressed, might you have any ideas?

Comment: yes, just put the line driver.switch_to.default_content() as the last one - after all operations with elements inside the frame

Answer (score 0):

If NoSuchElementException accrued and xpath is right then the scroll to target button :

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH OF Target button))
```

Comment: I just tried this with no avail. Might you have any other ideas? And yes the error I am getting is NoSuchElementException in case that helps. I think the reason it didn't work is because there is no scroll required. I will attach a picture in my original post of the button I am trying to press